# Should downstream object always be an Aggregate Root?

Tags: domain-driven-design

[Implementing DDD](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321834577), page 233:

> There are times when an object in a downstream Context must be
>   eventually consistent with the partial state of one or more Aggregates
>   in a upstream Context. In that case we'd design an Aggregate in the
>   downstream consuming Context, because Entities are used to maintain a
>   thread of continuity of change

According to the author, if *eventual consistency* is needed, then *downstream object* should always be an Aggregate Root. Is there a particular reason why it should never be designed as an *internal entity*?

UPDATE:

One could argue they always need to be the root to prevent having several downstream objects ( ie objects reflecting the state of upstream objects ) with the same id, but if synchronization is one way only ( from upstream to downstream context ), are there really no situations where it's ok for two downstream objects to have identical ids?

thanks

Comment: Depends, whether the downstream system uses the tactical patterns or not.

Comment: @Yves Reynhout: Aggregate Roots and Entities are tactical patterns.

Comment: I don't fully understand your question.  To be honest I don't think the downstream IDs are really that significant.  As long as you can get to the correct downstream object from the system of record AR.

Comment: @Eben Roux: I'm trying to get at the bottom of how author came to conclusion that downstream objects should ALWAYS be roots. Hence, I gave an example where synchronization is uni-directional (from upstream to downstream), since in that case there would be no confusion of several downstream objects ( all having different state and yet all representing the same upstream objects )trying to update the same upstream objects. I'd like to know why should even with uni-directional synchronization downstream objects always be roots

Comment: Ah, I see :) --- well, reading your reference the very next line is "But we should strive to avoid this modeling choice where possible.  When you can, choose Value Objects to model integrations."  Many choices are weighed up against each other and you need to choose what is relevant and works for you.  I, for one, don't really subscribe to these things in a black-or-white approach but rather use them as good guidelines and then come up with what I'm comfortable with.  Over time my opinions about my choices may even change.

Comment: @Eben Roux: "Many choices are weighed up against each other and you need to choose what is relevant and works for you." I understand that, but I'd also like to know the reasoning behind author's conclusion, since only then will I really be given a choice of whether to follow his or some other approach(if you don't know how one design came to be and what its benefits are, then you aren't really equipt to make design decisions, since you have no clue which design is better and why - I'm rambling again :D )

Comment: I don't think there is a one-size-fits-all in domain modeling.  I know Vaughn frequents the domain driven design group on yahoo so you may want to get the answer from the horse's mouth (if you haven't done so yet).  He is a very nice chap and is passionate about spreading the DDD word so I'm sure he'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a crack at this.

He is talking about a downstream bounded context, not a downstream object. That's the important phrase here.

In a different bounded context, you would need to communicate through an aggregate root in that context because a well established rule in DDD is that all communication goes through an aggregate root. You wouldn't call methods on an entity or value object inside that AR directly.

Also - the aggregate root is the unit of consistency in DDD. So as he says - if you need eventual consistency in an object that exists in a downstream bounded context, design an aggregate root (the consistency boundary) in that downstream bounded context.